# What is this little distance between elements?

Tags: html, css, dom

(Solved by suggestion of duplicate- I deleted whitespace between elements, like explained there: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements))

I am doing the HTML/CSS example for other ppl.

I have defined

```
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border: 0px;
 }

 body{
  width: 100%;
 }
```

And the

```
<div class="wrapper">
```

With styling

```
width: 1920px;
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
```

The wrapper **contains** the *aside*, and *main*

```
<aside>[...]</aside>
<main>[...]</main>
```

**Aside** is styled as:

```
position: relative;
width: 1010px;
padding-top: 100px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: lightgray;
```

**Main** is styled as:

```
  width: 810px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  background: #333 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 0px;
```

And my question is:
Why these elements don't stick together[?], between them is like 5 pixels of blank space.
http://scr.hu/8rxi/9smmb
(note: the red part of circle is another part of excercise)